# Attribuate a number from an other Dataframe - Series([], Name: id, dtype: float64)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributes

I have two pandas Dataframes, the first one named source in which we have ID and Names (ID, Username) 
 `source.head()`

[image]

The second one named data_code, in which we have also just unsernames (0) column and an code column in which I will try to get IDs in it.

```
data_code.head()
```

[image]

What I did is to create a function that will look for sames Usenames in two Dataframes and get the ID of the username from source Dataframe, if does not exist it will generate a random ID. In my solution I tried to create a dictionary in which  I will have only unique values.

```
uniqueIDs = data_code[0].unique()
FofToID= {}
```

Then I will fill the dictionary with Id using this function

```
for i in range(len(uniqueIDs)):   
  if uniqueIDs[i] in list(source["username"]): 
    FofToID[uniqueIDs[i]]= np.float_(source[source["username"]==i]["id"])  
  else:
    FofToID[uniqueIDs[i]]= int(random.random()*10000000)
```

the output was like below: 
[image]
My problem that all values existing in the `source` Dataframe get the value Series([], Name: id, dtype: float64). I tried to fix this problem but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, for non exist values `id` use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and last create `Series` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
source = pd.DataFrame({'id':[111111,222222,666666,888888], 'username':['aa','ss','dd','ff']})
data_code = pd.DataFrame({'code':[0]*4, 0:['ss','dd','rr','yy']})


FofToID = (data_code.merge(source, left_on=0, right_on='username', how='left')
               .fillna({'id': int(random.random()*10000000)})
               .set_index(0)['id']
               .to_dict()
                )
print (FofToID)
{'ss': 222222.0, 'dd': 666666.0, 'rr': 367044.0, 'yy': 367044.0}
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael for the solution, it generate a dictionary with the right values without the usernames , but I will fix it.

Comment: @FiliusTanit - yes, just testing with some data. So what is your final code?

Comment: @FiliusTanit - Added some sample data and solution was changed a bit, please check it.

Comment: your new solution gives me the right IDs but a constant id 
like this : {'pomouton': 9658462.0,
 'jbwlodarczyk': 9658462.0,
 'alex_barillet': 9658462.0,
 'nextdoor_fr': 9658462.0,
 'astridlhenry': 9658462.0,...}\

Comment: Like in your solution output {'rr': 367044.0, 'yy': 367044.0}

Comment: @FiliusTanit - What is exepcted output?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thanks @jezrael for his contribution, here is the final solution I get it:

`for i in range(len(uniqueIDs)):

     if uniqueIDs[i] in list(source["username"]): 
        FofToID[uniqueIDs[i]]= int(source[source["username"]==uniqueIDs[i]]["id"])

     else:
        FofToID[uniqueIDs[i]]= int(random.random()*10000000)`

the output look like that

[image]